# Target actively refusing request

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Im trying to build a program to transfer files through Python3 sockets.
Here is my server code:

```
# server.py

import socket                   # Import socket module

port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = "127.0.0.1"              # Get local machine name
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(4)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print ('Server listening....')

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print ('Got connection from', addr)

    filename='send.rtf'
    print ('File Assigned')
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    print ('File Oppened')
    l = f.read(1024)
    print ('Reading')
    while (l):
        conn.send(l)
        print('Sent ',repr(l))
        l = f.read(1024)
        print ('Reading')
    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    conn.close()
```

And here is my client code:

```
# client.py

import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = "127.0.0.1"              # Get local machine name
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))

with open('recieved', 'wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully got the file')
s.close()
print('Connection closed')
```

I have the server running on my Mac and the Client on my PC. The program runs fine if I run them both on my Mac, but not on separate machines. This is the error I get when I run the program on my PC:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gshin\Desktop\P2PFile\P2PFileClient2.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "127.0.0.1" is a **localhost** address. In order for 2 different machines to communicate, the server needs to be bound on its "public" *IP* (you can bind it on all of its addresses ("0.0.0.0")), and the client needs to connect to server's IP.

Comment: He's probably using 127.0.0.1 to test the code on the same machine.

Comment: I actually tried both neither worked but I got a different error. Gimme a little bit and Ill retry it

Comment: Also just to confirm, you mean set both host variables to 0.0.0.0 @CristiFati

Comment: No, just use that one when binding the socket on the server app. On the client app, use server's address (e.g. "192.168.....")

Comment: Sorry I don't know too much about IP's yet, just confirming that your talking about the public IP, like the one you get from googling, what is my IP.

Comment: Probably not the "public IP". Unless both your machines are directly accessible on the Internet. If you're behind a cable router, for example, the router itself has a public IP, but your machines probably have an address on your internal network that they can use to talk to each other. Run "ifconfig" from the command line on your Mac (or you can look in the Network tab of the System Preferences app). As @CristiFati suggested, you probably have a 192.168.N.N range of addresses being used in your internal network.

Comment: my IPv4 starts with 10.200 not 192.168 is that ok?

Comment: IT WORKS! I did it with the 10.200 and it worked